# How can I make the card as the default payment method during checkout flow

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe checkout to collect card details and customer address as shown below

```
 const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  payment_method_types: ['card'],
  mode: 'setup',
  customer: req.subscription.customerId,
  client_reference_id: email,
  metadata: {'plan': 'basic'},
  billing_address_collection: 'required',
  success_url: req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + '/payment/middle?'+queryParams,
  cancel_url: req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + '/payment/failure',
});
```

How can I make the card as the default payment method during checkout flow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Checkout Session automatically attaches the new payment method to the customer. If you want to then set this payment method as the default one for subscription payments, you need to manually update the `invoice_settings.default_payment_method` property of the customer object.

I recommend listening to the `checkout.session.completed` webhook and do this:

```
// The checkout session object sent by the webhook
const session = event.data.object;

// Retrieve the associated setup intent (we need it to get the payment_method just after)
const setupIntent = await stripe.setupIntents.retrieve(
    session.setup_intent
);
  
// Update the default payment method for the customer
const customer = await stripe.customers.update(session.customer, {
    invoice_settings: {
      default_payment_method: setupIntent.payment_method,
    },
});
```

You can learn more about this by reading [this page](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/subscriptions/update-payment-details) in the Stripe documentation.

Comment: It says ```{ Error: You can not pass `payment_intent_data` in `setup` mode.```

Comment: @Rajan Sorry I read your question too quickly and my answer was wrong. I just updated my reply.